# while True loop script stops running, no termination or error thrown

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-requests, python-requests-html

From running this code on a loop, it doesnt terminate or seem to end? No error is caught / thrown. It always does it once it is on line 189 on the output console.

```py
import time
from requests_html import HTMLSession

product_urls = ["https://footdistrict.com/en/adidas-yeezy-boost-700-ee9614.html", "https://footdistrict.com/en/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-static-ef2905.html"]
session = HTMLSession()

def monitor():
    try:
        for url in product_urls:
            print("Searching for url: {} ...\n".format(url))
            r = session.get(url,timeout=20)
            r.html.render()
            search = r.html.find(("#attribute134"), first =True)

            if search is not None: 
                print("Item is in stock.")  
            else:
                print("Item is out of stock.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    time.sleep(3)

while True:
    monitor()
```

Is it some kind of memory error causing this? I tried to increase `time.sleep(3)` to something like `time.sleep(30)` but this made no difference, still stops running after line 189 in console?

Comment: moniter doesn't return anything, while condion is always true, how you except that i will stop at some point ?

Comment: "From running this code on a loop, it **doesnt terminate** or seem to end?" "It always **does it** once it is on line 189" -- does it terminate or not?

Comment: It doesn't terminate. The code just fails to continue going, like it is stuck in a process and won't exit it @Blorgbeard

Comment: "fails to continue going" sounds like it terminates... Do you mean it stops printing output?

Comment: it stops printing output, it stops sending requests and doesn't continue @Blorgbeard

Comment: But the program does not end? If you run this from the command line, when it "stops working", you are not dumped back the command prompt?

Comment: correct, have you tried running it to see what happens?

Comment: I don't have the requests_html library installed - and I really shouldn't have to run your code to get a clear description of the behaviour you're seeing..